# ads-error 0x745 on twincat database server configuration

Tags: database, twincat, database-server, twincat-ads

I am trying to set a "MS SQL server" using "twincat database server configuration", and always get the following error: "ADS error 0x745: Timeout elapsed"
In the picture attach is the configuration settings I'm using, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: ADS error 0x745: Timeout elapsed usually means that a proper connection could not be made in 5 seconds (the default timeout). On the machine where the SQL stuff is running that connects with the PLC can you check with other tools if a connection can be made? Did you create (a) route(s)?